# Update and select statement in single query

Tags: sql

In SQL:

How to Update one column of a table from a column of another table and how to concatenate two column of first table in a single query

If column_1 of table_1 matches column_A of table_2, then update column_2 of table_1 from the values of column_B of table_2 and also concatenate column_3 and column_4 of table_1 into column_5 of table_1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the DBMS so I am assuming MS SQL SERVER, however this SQL is pretty standard.

```
UPDATE T1
  SET column_2 = T2.column_B,
      column5 = T1.column_3 + T1.column_4
FROM table_1 AS T1
JOIN table_2 AS T2
  ON T2.column_A = T1.column_1
```

Comment: @T McKeown  Will it work for Oracle DB? If not, could you tell me, how we have to reframe it?

Comment: @T McKeown No It shows syntax error. Its not even taking it.